# Update the field on closed opportunities

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a requirement to update the field on closed opportunities(won/lost) without reopening the records.

Please suggest if we do have any way of achieving this task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this.

closed (Lost/Won) opportunity can be updated using workflow.
Create a OnDemand workflow which will update field which you wish and run this on closed opportunity.
try to see if you get field updated.

I just tried it on one of my instance for closed opportunity and I updated description field. It did updated without reopening opportunity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked. But I wanted to update different values based on Opportunity ids. I have achieved this using Excel Online updating.